# How to retrieve photo of a telegram contact?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

In an app, we need to import contacts of a user. We found [Telegram.Link](https://github.com/enricostara/telegram.link/) which implements Telegram API. It has a method that retrieves contacts. A single contact is showed below:

```
{
T: api.type.UserContact,
id: 148049613,
first_name: "M.",
last_name: "Barezban",
username: "Barezban",
access_hash: "0x47ad17f617b9e945",
phone: "989363356056",
photo: {
  T: api.type.UserProfilePhoto,
  photo_id: "0x08d30ecd1b31a7bc",
  photo_small: {
    T: api.type.FileLocation,
    dc_id: 4,
    volume_id: "0x00000000192931a8",
    local_id: 75848,
    secret: "0xac6db13d308318b3"
  },
  photo_big: {
    T: api.type.FileLocation,
    dc_id: 4,
    volume_id: "0x00000000192931a8",
    local_id: 75850,
    secret: "0x4f302deb78247cce"
  }
},
status: {
  T: api.type.UserStatusOffline,
  was_online: 1463043346
}}
```

I found no way to download the profile photo. which method should I use?

I tried [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) which implements Telegram Bot API and has two method that could help me: `getUserProfilePhotos` and `getFile`.

I tried `bot.getUserProfilePhotos(148049613)` and got `telegram.error.NetworkError: Bad Request: user not found (400)`.

I also tried `bot.getFile('0x08d30ecd1b31a7bc')` and got `telegram.error.NetworkError: Bad Request: invalid file id (400)`

There is also a method named [upload.getFile](https://core.telegram.org/method/upload.getFile) that uses volume_id, local_id and secret but I don't know how to use and call this method.

So how can I download this photo?

Answer (score 0):

File download in Telegram API is done via:

```
upload.getFile#e3a6cfb5 location:InputFileLocation offset:int limit:int = upload.File;
```

See [upload.getFile](https://core.telegram.org/method/upload.getFile) as well as https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files

**NOTE** some of those API Types there are outdated ([look here for the latest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl)), but the gist of how file downloads work is explained there.

You have everything you need. In most cases you can download profile pictures with just one call to `upload.getFile` (up to 512 Kb). The [link](https://core.telegram.org/method/upload.getFile) above gives clear details.

1)For *InputFileLocation* use

```
api.type.FileLocation{
   dc_id: 4,
   volume_id: "0x00000000192931a8",
   local_id: 75850,
   secret: "0x4f302deb78247cce"}
```

2) For *offset* use: `0`

3) For *limit* use: `0`

Note that you need to send this from the proper connection, in this case a connection to dc_id = 4, to avoid

```
{error_code: 303, error_message: "USER_MIGRATE_4" / "FILE_MIGRATE_4"}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you know any implementation of this method in python or meteor(Node.js)?

Comment: @omid Sorry, I don't code much python. but is this not included in your telegram.link? you can extend the GitHub repo to do this, yes?